# change a numeric column to a factor and assign labels/levels to the data

Tags: r

I have a numeric column with values 1,2 and 3
I want to change it to a factor column and assign values i.e., 1 = Petrol, 2 = Hybrid and 3 = Diesel without changing the original data
how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using `levels` function. For example `dummy` data with three factor 1, 2 and 3,

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  fac = rep(c(1,2,3),4)
)
dummy$fac <- as.factor(dummy$fac)
```

In base `R`

## `R`-1

```
levels(dummy$fac) <- c("Petrol", "Hybrid", "Disesel")
```

## `R`-2

```
levels(dummy$fac) <- list("Petrol" = 1, "Hybrid" = 2, "Disesel" = 3)
```

Also, using `dplyr` package,

## `dplyr`

```
dummy$fac <- dplyr::recode_factor(dummy$fac, "1" = "Petrol", "2" = "Hybrid" , "3" = "Disesel")
```

All will give

```
       fac
1   Petrol
2   Hybrid
3  Disesel
4   Petrol
5   Hybrid
6  Disesel
7   Petrol
8   Hybrid
9  Disesel
10  Petrol
11  Hybrid
12 Disesel
```

And `str(dummy$fac)` is like

```
Factor w/ 3 levels "Petrol","Hybrid",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
```